# JDialog doesn't size correctly with wrapped JTextArea

Tags: jtextarea, jdialog, word-wrap

While making a program, I noticed a bug with the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` call. I use a button to create a JTextArea that wraps and then display a dialog containing this text area.

If the text area is too large, however, the dialog does not size itself correctly to the height of the JTextArea. The Dialog cuts off the OK button in this example.

I replicated the bug in the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class DialogBug {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final String text = "looooooooooooooooooooooong text looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text";

        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextArea area = new JTextArea(text, 0, 50);
                area.setEditable(false);
                area.setLineWrap(true);
                area.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                area.append(text);
                area.append(text);
                area.append(text);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, area, "why does it do this", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        });

        frame.add(button);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I would post a picture, but I don't have enough reputation...

Is there a way to fix this without having to use a JScrollPane?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the `pack` command on the dialog (a function in the [Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) class) it will resize based on subcomponents. For your case you will have to rewrite without using the `showMessageDialog()` to get the resize to work (so make the dialog first, add the text, pack, then show it)

```
Dialog b = new Dialog();
// add stuff
b.pack();
```

For my test code it worked perfectly to get the dialogs to be the right sizes

1. Without `pack()` [image: With Pack Command]
2. With `pack()` [image: With Pack Command]

Comment: It works! I still don't understand why showMessageDialog() won't pack() automatically. It's definitely more tedious to make your own JDialog and add in the OK and Cancel buttons yourself, since showMessageDialog() does that all for you, but at least it works.